# Possible to add multicolumn functionality to LaTeX mark down?

Tags: feature-request

I am not sure how LaTeX packages are loaded into StackExchanges like Stats, but I'm curious whether the multicolumn functionality can be added for arrays? I know some of the amsmath symbols are loaded since characters like $\nabla$ and $\mathbb{F}$ and $\mathcal{S}$ are loaded by default.

As an example, I was trying to implement this table as would appea

```
$$ 
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{W=0} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{W=1}& \\
 & X & \bar{X} & X & \bar{X} \\ \hline
Y & a & b & r & s \\
\bar{Y} & c & d & u & v \\
\end{array}$$
```

So that it was clear we depicted an X-Y relation stratified by groups according to W=0 and W=1, like this:

[image: Desired output]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/313635/23242

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica interesting and creative examples. Maybe I misunderstand they look like they span a whole row, or at least from a particular column until the end. I need two text displays to hover over two columns specifically. I gave my "want" example as would be rendered as desired in my standard tex compiler.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't bother to compile & see how it's supposed to look. But you'll need *some* workaround, as `\multicolumn` isn't supported by MathJax: https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/macros/index.html. (MathJax is an external service which converts a subset of LaTeX into MathML, so S.E. can't add functionality without writing & hosting its own extensions.)

Comment: Unrelatedly, I don't think you need the `$$`'s when you start & end the mathjax w/ `\begin{} ... \end{}`.

Comment: In light of @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica's comment, it might be worth trying to figure out if it can be done purely via MathML.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica: Even if it can, you'll still have to persuade S.E. to enable MathML markup in posts.